# How to bind an entity framework object to a listview

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework

This is the first time to ask here, so please help me convey what I mean.

First I used an entity framework and I want to make a query that retrieve data from 3 tables, and then bind the result to a list view, the problem here is that there are nothing appear on the page. That's what I made:

```
ITIEntities MyContext = new ITIEntities();
var Courses = MyContext.Courses;
var Instructors = MyContext.Instructors;
var Ins_Courses = MyContext.Ins_Course;
var Query= from Crs in Courses
           from Ints in Instructors
           from Instructor_courses in Ins_Courses
           where Crs.Crs_Id==Instructor_courses.Crs_Id
           && Instructor_courses.Ins_Id== Ints.Ins_Id
           select new 
           {
               Name=  Ints.Ins_Name,
               Salary=Ints.Salary,
               ListOfCourses=Crs.Crs_Name,
           };
MyListView.DataSource = Query;
MyListView.DataBind();            

MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: please show your markup. also why are you saving changes to context after a select?

Answer (score 1):

here problem is enumerable type variable Query so if you want to bind result to listview you have to define entity public class with getter and setter properties for each column which you want to show.

```
public Class ClassNameEntity
{

public string Name {get; set;}

}
```

use in linq query with following

```
 select new ClassNameEntity
{
Name= Ints.Ins_Name

}.ToList();
```

that will return list of your defined class object list so directly bind result of upper query.

```
ITIEntities MyContext = new ITIEntities();
            var Courses = MyContext.Courses;
            var Instructors = MyContext.Instructors;
            var Ins_Courses = MyContext.Ins_Course;
            List<ClassNameEntity> Query= from Crs in Courses
                       from Ints in Instructors
                       from Instructor_courses in Ins_Courses
                       where Crs.Crs_Id==Instructor_courses.Crs_Id
                       && Instructor_courses.Ins_Id== Ints.Ins_Id
                       select new ClassNameEntity
                       {
                           Name=  Ints.Ins_Name,
                           Salary=Ints.Salary,
                           ListOfCourses=Crs.Crs_Name,
                       }.ToList();
            MyListView.DataSource = Query;
            MyListView.DataBind();            

                MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: is it the only way brother?